# Most general linear transformation which leaves the origin fixed and preserves all distances?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on the following problem from Ahlfors (complex analysis):

Prove that the most general (linear) transformation which leaves the origin fixed and preserves all distances is either a rotation or a rotation followed by reflexion in the real axis.

I have the part about it being a rotation. Roughly,

Let $Sz = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. $S(0)=0$ implies that $b=0$. $|Sz|=|z|$ implies $|cz+d|=|a|=constant$ for all $z$, so that $c=0$ and $|a|=|d|$. Together they imply $Sz = \frac{a}{d} z$ where $|a/d| = 1$.

I'm not really sure where the reflexion in the real axis part of the question comes in. Is "reflexion in the real axis" the mapping $x+iy \mapsto -x+iy$ ? Would that not mean that it is no longer a linear transformation?

Comment: Reflection in the $x$-axis takes $x+iy$ to $x-iy$, it is conjugation.

Comment: How is a (linear) transformation defined in Ahlfors?

Comment: The phrase "is either a rotation or a rotation followed by reflexion in the real axis" (taken from Ahlfors) is not utterly wrong, but misleading. It's like saying that a man born in New York is either born in the USA or in China.

Comment: In fact, the most generalized transformation is not only the linear transformation.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion,

S(z)=az/d. Take T(z)=-az/d and R(z)=-z. 
 Then T is a rotation, R is a reflexion in the real axis and RT(z)=S(z).
 So S is a rotation followed by reflexion in the real axis.

Comment: $R(z) = -z$ is a rotation, not a reflection.